# Setting UP disaster recovery , one region to multi region in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, internal-dns, disaster-recovery, google-cloud-dns

I'm new to GCP and also learning about Multi-Regional architectures .
We already have single region ( but multi zonal ) infrastructure setup.
DNS names of the internal components do not have region/zone value mentioned in that.

I wanted to know thoughts about setting up multi-regional architecture where components in different region should be connecting to same region's components when making a call to connect.

One way, I thought of is adding the region/zone data in the DNS name and as per the Name resolution order policy of Google Cloud DNS, it will try to "find a private zone that matches as much of the requested record as possible (longest suffix matching). "

But in that case multiple changes have to made in the existing coding.
Is there any other way by which we can accommodate  such change ?

thanks

Comment: VPC networks on Google Cloud have default internal DNS service that lets instances in the same network access each other by using internal DNS names. But you can override that when you create an outbound/inbound  server policy or a private zone. Google Cloud searches for DNS records in an order using VPC name resolution[1], Based on your use case you may find the article on best practices for Cloud DNS private zones[2] helpful.[1] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#vpc-name-resolution-order
[2] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/best-practices#best_practices_for_private_zones

Comment: You may also look into these articles[3][4][5]that discuss disaster recovery in Google Cloud.

[3] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-planning-guide
[4] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-for-applications
[5] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-for-data